# why doesnt android studio show runtime errors consistently?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 0.8.9.  Sometimes when I click run and the app crashes, I don't see any errors show on the console.  Perhaps I am looking at the wrong window, but poking around I dont see any stacktrace.

Comment: do you see any sigabrt or sigsegv errors in your logcat? these can cause the debugger to disconnect meaning you won't get any further logs

Comment: It's a bug with AS. Sometimes re-plugging the cable helps, sometimes `abd kill-server && adb start-server` helps. If they don't work, go `adb logcat`.

Comment: just to make sure, would the stacktrace be under run or devices?

Answer (score 2):

Select the android tab at the bottom.  On the top right corner of that window, there is a tiny icon that shows an android behind a gear.  That button is "restore android logcat".  That shows the trace.

Android studio is a terribly designed IDE from a UX point of view.  Another question is, why do the scrollbars lack arrows?

Comment: because it's related.  you are downvoting a solution that works. I was pointing out something that was visually obscure.

Comment: Why did Google see fit to completely move to a new and foreign IDE for 90%+ developers who were happily using Eclipse .. (Eclipse has issues to, but it's mature). Like Android development is so easy, a new IDE will be "fun"